# PHP global variable loses value during web request

Tags: php, global-variables

I have a utility class with a static function that utilizes a global variable:

```
private static function isRateLimited($ip) {
    global $memcached_node;

    $memcache = new Memcache;
    $memcache->connect($memcached_node['host'], $memcached_node['port']) or die ("memcache failure");

    // do stuff
}
```

The global variable is set up via a chef cookbook. Everything has been working well within the application until a recent change. The change tweaked code execution so that `isRateLimited()` is called twice during a single web request.

Debugging has revealed that, the first time `isRateLimited()` is called, the global variable is set and everything work as expected. However, the second time `isRateLimited()` is called, the global variable returns an empty value (as tested with `empty()`). The result is that the second connection to memcached fails.

The global is not overwritten or unset anywhere else in the code. **Why does the global variable lose its value between executions of the function in the same web request?**

For reference, I tried referring to the global using `$memcached_node = $GLOBALS["memcached_node"];` as one of my "last ditch effort" darts. The behavior was the same.

### Environment

- PHP 5.3.4 (cli) (built: Jan 21 2011 00:08:14)
- nginx 1.0.6

Comment: It's not answering why, but obviously, the global variable is unset. Fire up the debugger and check where it gets changed.

Comment: As an alternative, strip your code right down to the bare minimum.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static function isRateLimited($ip) {
    var_dump(debug_backtrace()); // or log to file - whatever suits the context
    // ...
}
```

You can trace the call with PHP's `debug_backtrace()` function ([more info here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)).  Alternatively, you can increment a global counter variable and only do this for the *nth* call to `isRateLimited()` for a given server request if you know definitively which call is erroneous.

Answer (score 0):

Had the similar problem, before static function call global variable exists, inside static function it is empty. It is becoming empty on global keyword. But I was loading code via bootstrap for PHPunit. Without PHPunit it worked as expected.

What I ended up doing is to explicitly assigning variable as super global:

```
$GLOBALS['foo'] = $foo;
```